# Ajax and PHP specialchars issues

Tags: ajax

When i send a form contains data from inputs without specialchars, it reaches the PHP file and get set in DB in ease.
Also when selecting, there are no problems at all.

But, when user types the next keys, the thing is different:
" or ' or `<script>` or alert('yes'); or \ or $ and so for and so on.

What i've tried:
Using tons of encodeURI or encodeURIComponent functions or JSON.stringify
or escapeHTML and what i didn't try..
but nothing works.
the most problematic is: `<script>` or alert('yes');
which are not only that not being sent to the PHP file, they stuck the whole page!

notice: now ive noticed that even here in stackoveflow, when i write `<script>` tag not in a code brackets, stackoverflow displays just nothing!

now, some strings, somehow, finally get delivered to the php file,
but i also have the continious problem when im trying to store them:
they are in json encoded, so i wont do each object key some long and time consuming functions like htmlspecialchars / mysqli_real_escape_string /
htmlentities or others.. it will be very uncomfortable to work like this....

an example of the html/php first page:

```
<div class="contact-form">
      <form ng-submit="processForm()" class="default-form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="">* שם פרטי ושם משפחה</label>
            <input type="text" required ng-model="formData.full_name" placeholder="* שם פרטי ושם משפחה">
                    </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="">* כתובת דוא׳׳ל</label>
            <input type="text" required ng-model="formData.email" placeholder="* כתובת דוא׳׳ל">
                    </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="">* טלפון</label>
            <input type="text" required ng-model="formData.phone" placeholder="* טלפון">
                    </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="">* סוג קבלן</label>
            <select required ng-model="formData.type">
              <option value="">* סוג קבלן</option>
              <option value="פרטי" alt="">פרטי</option>
              <option value="יזם" alt="">יזם</option>
              <option value="בנייה ציבורית" alt="">בנייה ציבורית</option>
            </select>
                    </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <label for="">
              העלאת קבצים
            </label>
            <input type="file" ng-file-model="formData.files" name="files" multiple style="margin-top:15px">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top:40px">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.newsletter" id="newsletter" >
            <label for="newsletter">קבל מבצעים ועדכונים במייל</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top:10px">
            <button class="thm-btn bg-clr1" style="color:white; font-weight:bold" type="submit">לשליחה לחץ כאן</button>
            <h3 class="loader" style="display:none">טוען ומעלה קבצים...</h3>
          </div>
                </div>
      </form>
```

as you can see, just another angular based form.

now the JS file:

```
$scope.formData = {
  full_name: "raz",
  phone: "0509921014",
  email: "razwebs@gmail.com",
  type: "בנייה ציבורית",
  newsletter: true,
  files: "",
};

$scope.processForm = function() {
  $(".bg-clr1").hide();
  $(".loader").show();
  var data = new FormData();
  if ($scope.formData.files.length>0)
  {
    var files = $scope.formData.files;
    for (var k=0; k<files.length; k++)
      data.append("file-"+k, files[k]);
  }
  var formData = JSON.stringify($scope.formData);
  formData = encodeURIComponent(formData);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'send_quote.php?formData=' + formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $(".bg-clr1").show();
      $(".loader").hide();
      //window.location = "thanks.php";
    }
  });
};
```

note that in this js file, im also sending post and get, which post is the FormData object contains files, and the get contains the regular strings.

and finally the php page:

```
$array = $_FILES;
$files = [];
for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
{
  $file = $_FILES["file-" . $i];
    $name = $file["name"];
    $fileType = $file["type"];
    $tmp_name = $file["tmp_name"];

    $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    $fileId = rand(1,10000000);
    $dir = "admin/uploads/";
    $randName = $dir . $fileId . "." . $ext;

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $randName);
  array_push($files, $randName);
}
$formData = urldecode($_GET['formData']);
$fd = json_decode($formData, true);
$fd["files"] = $files;
$fd = json_encode($fd, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$theDate = time();
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO quotes
(
  `quote`,
  `status`,
  `date`
)
VALUES
(
  '$fd',
  0,
  '$theDate'
)
");
```

hope it seems clear, i really spent tons of hours to solve this issue,
nothing works, its really frustrated and i sure others facing the same issue as well...

if someone can help, it will be awesome, and sorry for medium level english.

thanks!

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: posted, you may look

Comment: Use parameterized queries to insert data into your database

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string would do the job as well?